# CPU Usage and Object.wait

Tags: java, performance, profiling, cpu, wait

I was profiling my application using JProfiler and as result, in "CPU Views" section it shows that more than 40% of CPU time is spent on `Object.wait()`. However as far as I know on `Object.wait()` CPU is not given to the waiting thread.

Could somebody help understand what's going on and why the profiler shows that this much of CPU is spent on `Object.wait()`?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads or just one? is this a GUI application or a server?

Comment: It's a non-GUI application which contains many threads - between 40 to 60 - threads. Some threads are waiting for network I/O and some other are waiting to respond to the requests receiving using I/O.

Answer (score 7):

The profiler does not know that the CPU is idle while in `wait()`. All that the profiler knows is that `wait()` was entered, and several milliseconds later it returned. So, if those milliseconds tend to take up 40% of your execution time, there you have it.

Comment: Depends on the profiler. For example, YourKit definitely knows to measure CPU time: http://www.yourkit.com/docs/10/help/times.jsp

Comment: @EliAcherkan Yes, and I do not even know for sure that jprofiler does not know that; but there is no other explanation. The only other thing I could speculate is that if you have one thread in a tight loop doing nothing but `wait()` and another thread in a tight loop doing nothing but `notify()` then I suppose it is likely that `wait()` would in fact consume a big percentage of the CPU, not because it is expensive in and of itself, but because we would not really be doing anything else. But that's highly unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

40% of what? Suppose you profile the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  sleep(1);
}
```

If you look only at CPU time (not wall-clock time), nearly all of it will be in `sleep`.

Why? Because it's using very little CPU time at all, but of the CPU time it *is* using, nealy all of it is spent entering and leaving `sleep`.

Of course, if you do look at wall-clock time, even more of it will be in `sleep`.

Same goes for any blocking call, like `wait`.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I'll try another profiler like YourKit to see what it tells me.

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler distinguishes between various thread states. The displayed time for the wait method depends on the thread state selector in the upper right corner of the CPU views. Please see http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/07/thread-states-in-cpu-profiling-views.html for more information.